# Can I re-count the verticalHeader when I go to hide a row of QTableView?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'll use some filtering criteria to hide some of the rows, I want the verticalHeader to redisplay the sequence number:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui


class MyQTableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyQTableView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.setModel(self.model)

        self.init_data(['title'], [('a',), ('b',), ('c',)])

    def init_data(self, headers, datas):
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers)
        for row, rows in enumerate(datas):
            for column, data in enumerate(rows):
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem(f'{data}')
                self.model.setItem(row, column, item)
                if row == 1:
                    #To hide a row
                    self.setRowHidden(1, True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    table = MyQTableView()
    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The actual QTableView is as follows:

```
     title

1     a

3     c
```

The expected QTableView  as：

```
     title

1     a

2     c
```

Comment: You can set the data again for the vertical header using `model.setHeaderData`

Comment: If you want to *properly* filter rows, you should use a [QSortFilterProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html), not hide those rows: if you have 3 rows spanning from 1 to 3 and you hide row two, the second *displayed* row is still the third row in the model.

Comment: setHeaderData works on a single row, I use setVerticalHeaderLabels instead, but this requires rescanning all the rows and generating a new sequence of lineno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case instead of hiding rows it is better to use a QSortFilterProxyModel where it overrides the headerData so that it does not depend on the sourceModel and implementing the custom filter.

```py
class FilterProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return section + 1
        return super().headerData(section, orientation, role)

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
        if row == 1:
            return False
        return True


class MyQTableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyQTableView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.proxy_model = FilterProxyModel()
        self.proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.setModel(self.proxy_model)

        self.init_data(["title"], [("a",), ("b",), ("c",)])

    def init_data(self, headers, datas):
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers)
        for row, rows in enumerate(datas):
            for column, data in enumerate(rows):
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem(f"{data}")
                self.model.setItem(row, column, item)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Does QSortFilterProxyModel can only be called once? If the number of filtered rows changes dynamically?

Comment: @Alex QSortFilterProxyModel will filter the items every time something changes in the model. Note that in my code I never call you to filter something explicitly, but when adding items, the model changed something, so the filter was applied.

Comment: Hi, @eyllanesc I found that using the QStandardItemModel.setItem method will trigger QSortFilterProxyModel.filterAcceptsRow many times, while the QStandardItemModel.appendRow method will only be triggered once, so what should I do when initializing or adding data?

Comment: I tried the appendRow method is better than setItem in this case:
self.model.appendRow([QtGui.QStandardItem(f"{data}") for data in rows])